# My view is not being rendered (ASP. NET / Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller that is sending an array with json objects.
Instead of showing me the view, only the contents of the array are shown in the browser.

thank you.

My controller:

```
 public JsonResult IndexJson()
    {

        var equipas = db.Equipas.Select(t => new { Nome = t.Nome, Abreviatura = t.Abreviatura, Country = t.Country }).ToList();

        return Json(equipas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "getAll";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div ng-app="ruyApp" ng-controller="equipasCtrl">

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Nome
    </th>
    <th>
        País
    </th>
    <th>
       Abreviatura
    </th>

</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
    <td>
        {{x.Nome}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{x.Country}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{x.Abreviatura}}
    </td>


</tr>

</table>

</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/AngularScripts.js"></script>
```

My script:

```
var app = angular.module('ruyApp', []);

app.controller('equipasCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/Equipas/IndexJson').then(function (response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data;
    $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
    $scope.statuscode = response.status;

});
});
```

Browser output:

```
[{"Nome":"Real Madrid","Abreviatura":"RM","Country":"Espanha"},{"Nome":"Benfica","Abreviatura":"BEN","Country":"Portugal"},{"Nome":"FC Porto","Abreviatura":"FCP","Country":"Portugal"},{"Nome":"Barcelona","Abreviatura":"BAR","Country":"Espanha"},{"Nome":"PSG","Abreviatura":"PSG","Country":"França"},{"Nome":"Charlotte Hornets","Abreviatura":"CHA","Country":"EUA"},{"Nome":"Boston Celtics","Abreviatura":"BOS","Country":"EUA"},{"Nome":"Indiana Pacers","Abreviatura":"IND","Country":"EUA"}]
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. Do you need to parse the JSON or something?

Comment: it looks like your NET server not configured correctly and instead angular router your request processed by server and brings you the json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why that code does not work. I solved the question by putting the ng-init directive with the parse of the model.

**View**

```
<div ng-app="ruyApp" ng-controller="equipasCtrl" ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))">

</div>
```

**Script**

```
app.controller('equipasCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.init = function (equipas) {
$scope.myData = equipas;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you return other result than ViewResult, the ViewEngine is not triggered and no view is returned. I would return the json as a model to the view: ex. return this.View(jsonEquipas) Or pass the equipas as a property to the view model you pass to the view.